# My canvas/graph jumps to left after creating the object

Tags: bootstrap-4, chart.js

chart.js is great and I am creating my first chart. But I have one problem I can't figure out. After creating the object, my canvas/graph jump to the left, although I have text-centered using bootstrap4. The canvas is in the right place at the beginning as well. The code reproducing the problem is:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="my_graph" class="col-sm-12 text-center">Graph: <br></div>
            <button id="test_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test_button</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap validator -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
    <!-- chart.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Import custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the js is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my_graph').append('<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000">');
});

$('#test_button').click(function (event) {
    drawGraph();  
})

function drawGraph() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    myLineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [0],
            datasets: [{
                data: [0],
                label: "nr1",
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: false
        }
    });
}
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please add a minimal code example snippet (No way to know why without seeing this bug/"jump"). If you show/hide an image inside `myGraph` you also get a "jump"? (Maybe this issue related to flexbox grid and not to chart.js).

Comment: Hi and thank you. I edited the snippet to reproduce the problem. Also a bootstrap4 tag for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem...!

On initial time the `canvas` is set to `display: block` you need to change into this `display: inline-block;` after `;` **semi-colon** on canvas tag under `style`

You can add `align="center"` or `class="text-center"` on `canvas` tag as you wish

Eg:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" align="center" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000; display: inline-block;">
```

This is Solution you can check here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_graph').append('<canvas id="myCanvas" align="center" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000; display: inline-block;">');
});

$('#test_button').click(function(event) {
  drawGraph();
})


function drawGraph() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    
  myLineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [0],
      datasets: [{
        data: [0],
        label: "nr1",
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: false
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="my_graph" class="text-center" >Graph: <br></div>
            <button id="test_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">test_button</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap validator -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
    <!-- chart.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Import custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="./js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, "display:inline-block" solved it. But why is it in the right place after initialization?
I have a second canvas, which works exactly how I did it, but without chart.js/an object like myLineGraph.